# How to solve Intellij Idea sync / indexing problem

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, indexing, synchronization

[image: example image]

How to fix the sync / indexing problem of IntelliJ Idea?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, these two steps solved the problem:

[image]